# What do these "for" loops do?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I'm only familiar with normal for loop declaration. Can anybody tell me what these for-loops are doing and how their conditions work?

```
BufferedReader charSource = Files.newBufferedReader(this.sourcePath, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2");

BufferedWriter charSink = Files.newBufferedWriter(this.targetPath, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2");

                for (String line = charSource.readLine(); line != null; line = charSource.readLine()) {
                for (final String element : line.split("\\s")) {
                    if (!element.isEmpty()) {
                        this.streamSorter.write(element);
                        elementCount += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It is clearly explained in the official Oracle tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html),

Comment: Have you tried running this code and stepping through the code with a debugger?  What do you think this code does?  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both iterate, obviously, with the main difference being the first checks a condition to continue after each iteration. In this case, if readLine() does not return null.

The second splits line into a collection of strings and iterates over each string.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing not normal here.

1. declare a `String` variable `line`, initialize to `charSource.readLine()`;
2. test if `line != null`, if `false`, end loop;
3. run body;
4. `line = charSource.readLine()`, goto 2.

The second one is **[enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)**, it can loop through any instance of `Iterable`, and will use the `Iterator` given by `Iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

The first one iterates over all lines and stops iterating after the last line (`readLine() returns null`), the second one over all words (`foreach` loop over the result of the `split` command).

The second loop uses the result of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

That's a for-each loop. 
It simply iterates over each element in a particular collection.
It's the easiest way of reaching all the elements in the collection.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

First, the external loop (The "for (String line = ..."):

For loops are basically while loops "masked". The three "pieces" of a for declaration are: The counter initialitation, the counter top specification, and the counter increment. As you can see, the for is really a while.

In your example (The external for), this is exactly what are you doing: The "counter" initialitation ("line = charSource.ReadLine()"), the "counter" top specification ("line != null") and the "counter" increment ("line = charSource.readLine()").

The internal loop is basically a foreach loop. A foreach loop iterates "automagically" over a collection, giving you the iterated item step by step.